How to find timestamp in binary file?
I am searching for the specific timestamp of 7:12:53am Monday April 22, 2024 within a binary file (Sunday, April 21, 2024 9:12:53 in UTC). I am using a hex editor and have been searching for the epoch time of 1713733973 (as both hex and int number) with no luck!
Any tips would be great, thank you!
I have tried

reading & searching in plain text notepad++ to spot string timestamps
searching for epoch time in hex editor as both a hex and int number

